# path-based routing for alb ingress controller doesn't work properly

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer, ingress-controller

I am trying path-based routing on the ALB ingress controller. However, although the "/" path works, the "/test" path gives a 403 error. When I move the app service from "/test" path to "/" path, it works here. So there is only a routing to the "/" path, not the other paths.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ui
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    # Ingress core settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: test-dev
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: project=test, env=dev
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: dev
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order: 1000
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80,"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: xxx
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.response-403: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"403","messageBody":"403 External access to endpoint not allowed"}}
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "xxx.test.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-ui
            port:
              number: 80
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    # Ingress core settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: test-dev
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: project=test, env=dev
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: dev
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80,"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: xxx
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.response-403: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"403","messageBody":"403 External access to endpoint not allowed"}}
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "xxx.test.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 8080
```

I expect routing to be done to paths other than only "/".

- AWS Load Balancer controller is installed by helm and version is v2.6.1
- Kubernetes version: 1.27
- EKS version: 1.27

Answer (score 0):

Could you please paste error, I tried it but its giving me `404` because nothing is running on service:`/test`
And its Path is not redirection if you are thinking the service should only work with `/test` if path is exist

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. 
From the service logs: 
Someone asked for the nonwhitelisted file "/test".  If this should be accessible, add it to the static web assets.

From website: 
Access to xxx.xxx.com was denied
You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403

As I understood from what you said, ingress can't redirect the page to path. That's why we need to add "/test" to the code side. This can be the reason because we don't have "/test" path from code side. I will try it and write what I found.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 2 ingress in same ingress group. One ingress might override the other. So, You have to add an order number of your ingress resource.

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order: '10'
```

The number can be 1-1000. The lowest number for all ingresses in the same ingress group is evaluated first. All ingresses without this annotation are evaluated with a value of zero. Duplicate rules with a higher number can overwrite rules with a lower number.

Important:

```
`Ensure that each ingress in the same ingress group has a unique priority number. You can't have duplicate order numbers across ingresses.`
```

For more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html